Users answer low-quality questions and deny OP deletion because they gain(ed) reputation
After reading relevant Help Center articles (mainly on duplicates), I'm still at loss, and I would very much like some input from more experienced users and moderators.
Assume a question is asked. It is then quickly marked as a duplicate, closed, and at the same time downvoted for unspecified reasons. I would assume, and this is important in my opinion, that the downvotes imply the post to be of low quality (for any reason), except being a duplicate, because duplicates should be handled by close-votes. Please correct me if wrong.
The problem now, is that someone answers the question and gets upvotes and essentially holds the post hostage as it can no longer be deleted as long as someone (and I quote the error message), "(...) have invested time and effort into answering it.". The answer's author now have personal gain from keeping the post alive as they have obtained and may receive more reputation from it, regardless of SO guidelines.
I recently posted a question which was not arguable a low-quality question: at the very end the conclusion was a typo that led run time errors that was difficult to interpret correctly. The question was (correctly) closed as a dupe, and downvoted. It was also decently answered, by a high-rep user, which gained several upvotes.
The OP then requests the answer to be removed so that the post can be deleted. The answerer denies, stating that his answer is better than those on the duplicate posts. OP then suggests they publish their answer on those posts, but they do not oblige nor respond.
So my question is, what is the correct approach here? I would have thought, for the greater good and quality of SO posts, that such a low-quality, duplicate post should be deleted? And I find it frustrating that a high-rep user would block the deletion for what seems to me, be personal gain rather than what would be in the community's best interest. They should know better, or am I completely off in this?

Read this as cynical if you want, but some of the users with very high reputation have high reputation because they haven't yet "learned" about the VTC/Duplicate feature(s). Unfortunately (?), closing as a duplicate doesn't give the voter(s) any rewards; there's no incentive other than to make the site better (as having all the solutions in one place is better™ for users), but answering the same question(s) over and over again reaps reputation and worthless internet points are what drives many here.

In situations like this it may not be a bad idea to ask mods to delete it. It's usually not something that we do, but if you explain that you believe your question isn't as good as the duplicates and you can't delete it yourself, a mod might look onto it favourably. In the worst case you will get one declined flag.

But in general, leave it. If the community thinks this is a poor signpost they will eventually delete it via votes. If not, then what really is the harm? We have got loads worse questions that should be deleted.

But why does it need to be deleted? We don't generally delete duplicates anyway, and especially not if they have a useful answer.

Note: Many duplicates will get downvotes dues to "lack of research" even if the question is well written.  Note also that any downvoted question can eventually be deleted, and if it gets 3 downvotes then people with high enough rep can vote to delete straight away (another reason that dups are often downvoted) (and as it turns out, is exactly what has happened to your question). And to clarify, the question cannot be answered after it has been closed. The answer has to have been made (or at least in progress) prior to having been closed.

To put words in their mouth, Dale is talking about that we (the curators) can vote to delete a closed immediately if it has a score <= -3, @user3840170 . If it doesn't, there's a "wait" period.

@CodyGray I'm sorry, maybe I should reformulate this post to make my point more clearly: It is not about deleting duplicates, it is about deleting low-quality posts. The fact that it's a duplicate is maybe a side track and given too much attentions (my bad). It is addressed because the answerer used it as an argument for not deleting. Also I wanted to distinguish between "downvotes" and "(dupe) closevotes". To the point: it was a low-quality question, it was downvoted, but it was answered; should it be deleted? I thought yes.

@user3840170 correct, sorry I forgot the "any closed downvoted" question. And the close reastis not relevant, duplicates are as closed as any other reason.

@Wololo the answer is "yes" but the great news is you don't have to be the judge nor try and accomplish that yourself. If the community agrees that it's a low quality question and should be deleted, then the community will action that - because at your current rep you can't assist that process other than down voting the answer, if you think it is a poor quality answer.

DaleK, i second that. I also concur with @Dharman ‘s commentary. I can live happily with this, but no one’s writing an answer yet, though it gets lots of downvotes. Would appreciate if people gave reasons so that maybe one could learn something.

@Wololo up/down votes on meta have a different meaning. More along the lines of "I Agree" or "I Disagree" rather than its good or bad quality. It has no impact on anything, and most meta questions get some downvotes. So certainly don't worry about it.

"The OP then requests the answer to be removed so that the post can be deleted." That is not what happened, unless some comments were deleted. You asked for the answerer to remove an upvote, when there is no indication that he upvoted at all.

Your question was rightfully deleted. I've seen high rep users deliberately writing answers to well-known duplicates before. By posting here a link to the question you've started a meta effect which will gain more reps for the answer to the user.

We also discourage new members from deleting their "bad" questions because that actually increases the chance that they will get question-banned. (That shouldn't be an issue for you, though). When possible, it's much better to repair a bad question than to delete it, because deletion doesn't actually make the badness go away.

The larger problem of "Fastest Gun in the West" answerers is well-known. You might want to search for FGITW on this site for some examples.

@PM2Ring, I agree. I already have another negative question, but I do not request that deleted because I sincerely believe it to be good, or at least ok, and could be of help to someone else. This post, which I tried to remove, was not good, and beyond repair. It is a lesson learned.

@user12002570 , This 'meta-effect', is it considered bad practice? Should we avoid linkage to external SE posts?

@Wololo Yes exactly. Avoid adding links to the question unless absolutely necessary. Here I don't think the link to the original question is necessary. People will just undelete it for fun or just because they can.

[1/2] This meta post leaves a strange taste. A person helps you by answering your question, and you bring this to meta and blame him for "answering a low-quality question". (You say "the conclusion was a typo", but the typo was introduced in an edit made after you got the answer.) I also think it's not completely fair to blame the answerer for answering a supposed duplicate. (It's not a 100% match: your misconception was "a enum is not its underlying type", while the dupes are "how to determine the underlying type", and while they do end up answering your question, ...

[2/2] ... I understand not immediately realizing that they're a valid dupe target.) And lastly, when the meta effect swings the way you don't like, you remove the link. :/ (Meta effect is problematic when it leads to people being downvoted into oblivion, that causes unnecessary stress. But here it just increases the post visibility. If it causes the post to be undeleted, then that's what the consensus is.)

@HolyBlackCat , [1/2] I'm sorry, I no longer know what to do, please tell me. It is not my intention to throw blame: Are my wording too harsh, should I reformulate? I did not come here for sympathy. I came here seeking guidance on how I should handle the situation, and I got an answer which I'm perfectly fine with and have accepted. I certainly do not understand what you mean by "when the meta effect swings the way you don't like (...)"?I removed the link because it was pointed out to me, here in the comments, that it was bad meta-practice: I have no issues putting it back in. Should I?

[2/2] I'm glad you didn't realize it was a dupe at first, because that means my edits in trying to salvage the post (before the typo) had some effect. If you look at the history, the duplication was much clearer at first. This is a sincere request, please tell me what I should do or should've done differently. Do you agree with the accepted answer? Clearly, posting on meta (in the way I did) is not it.

@Wololo you've done completely fine, everything you did was in good faith and with the intention of making the site a better site and of you being a better user of the site. Don't worry at all about the effects of one question and one meta post... that tiny in the scheme of things. More importantly your understanding going forward has improved. The great thing about meta is that everyone can air their opinions, but you don't need to keep everyone happy :)

[1/3] Maybe I misunderstood the undertone of this post, and if so, sorry for that. The context here is that there's a certain group of users that thinks we should be closing way more questions than we currently do instead of answering them (see the first comment under this post). Which might be true to some extent, but it also often gets taken too far, with questions getting closed as duplicates of vaguely related questions. This group is also over-represented on meta (because, you know, they're not busy answering questions :P). So the meta is always ready to bash people for answering ...

[2/3] ...questions they're not "supposed to" (again, see the first comment). Which, again, isn't necessarily a bad thing, but if you're satisfied with the answer you got, it's probably not the best move to bring meta's spotlight to the answerer and have them chewed out for helping you. Regarding "when the meta effect swings the way you don't like": maybe you don't share the sentiment of user12002570 (sorry if I misjudged), but what they effectively said is that you should remove the link while the question is deleted (which this their and yours desired outcome) to not have someone reopen...

[3/3] ...it, which is a bit questionable (the question could fluctuate between being deleted/undeleted until a consensus is reached, which you can stop by removing the link when it's in the "desired" state). It doesn't really matter in the grand scheme of things, and it seems in this case people weren't keen on undeleting it anyway (so I'm not suggesting to add the link back), but it's still something I'd avoid in the future (perhaps by not posting the link the first place).

@HolyBlackCat Thank you for elaborating! Would you care to join a (very) short chat? One clarification on my part: I was not content with the answer on the post being discussed. I was content with the answer on this meta-post. That is, I (learned and) understand now that it is not my job, responsibility and most importantly not my privilege (ref my rep) to determine closure/deletion of the post in question.

I see, thanks for claifying. Then my point doesn't apply.

When I have spent time and effort answering a question, and the next minute OP deletes it I feel cheated (even without any upvotes.)

tl;dr;
You should do nothing :)
Why?
Great attitude. Thank you for trying to ensure Stack Overflow contains good quality questions.
OPs can't and shouldn't delete their own question when it has received an answer because that would open the system up to the possibility of the OP abusing the system. Instead trust the existing curation tools that already result in bad quality questions being deleted.
Certainly not all duplicates are bad questions and the intention of the system is that good quality duplicates provide different search pathways to the same answer.
Clarification:
Duplicate closed questions are subject to the same downvote reasons as any other close reasons. In addition they may be downvoted due to "Lack of research" i.e. OP could have searched for and found the duplicate themselves.
Further, users over a certain reputation can vote to delete closed questions with a net vote less than or equal to -3. So sometimes such users will downvote duplicate questions in order to facilitate a quick deletion.
Finally, closed questions with a net vote less than or equal to -1 can eventually be voted for deletion (by the same high rep users, after 3 days I think), but by then its off most curators radar.

How can allowing the authors to delete their answered questions allow for gaming the system?

Maybe gaming is the wrong term, abusing is probably better, they can ask a question get an answer then delete it again which  is against the licence agreement and negates the hardwork the person put into writing an answer..

@CPlus Many homework cheats delete their question as soon as they get answer, to hide the evidence that they cheated. It's a minor problem on SO, but it's a severe problem on some stacks, eg Math.SE.

@PM2Ring That is gaming their school system more so than gaming Stack Overflow systems, but OK.

@CPlus Agreed, it's not gaming the SO system. But it's still abusing the SO community. And it certainly doesn't feel nice when some OP deletes their question after you've put time & energy into writing a decent answer for it.

@PM2Ring, However, it could significantly heighten the bar for answering low-quality and (to-be-deleted) homework questions in general. Hence, leaving those unanswered and reduce the appeal for asking them in the first place. Just a thought.

@Wololo I'm afraid it won't work like that. For that to work, it would need to be painfully clear that a question is going to be deleted. And even then... I really wonder if people pay that amount of attention to what they do when they're in "I answer to help out!" mode.

@CPlus There's a user who posts in the [tag:scipy] tag who posts a question, waits for an answer, then self-deletes, waits a day, and posts substantially the same question, so that they can get more answers. I find this really frustrating. There's no way to search another user's deleted posts, so unless this has happened to you, there's no indication to people writing an answer that this user does this.

@NickODell Sounds like that warrants a mod flag maybe.
